# how to attach mdf file to crystal reports

Tags: .net, vb.net, crystal-reports

I am trying to attach an mdf file to crystal report. Can anyone tell how to do it ??

I have added CrystalReport1.rpt to my project. Now what to do ??

Comment: A `.mdf` file is a SQL Server database. You need to have SQL Server installed on a machine (possibly SQL Server Express on your local machine), attach the `.mdf` to SQL Server, and then get your data for Crystal Reports from SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install mssql server , with user instance support,

and change your connection string in crystal report like this:

```
data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|Registration.mdf;User Instance=true
```

EDIT 1:

for more info see [this](http://rbgupta.blogspot.de/2007/12/sql-server-user-instances-and.html)